# What do the GCC compiler messages tell me to focus on to get the loop to vectorize?

Tags: gcc, optimization, vectorization, compiler-flags

**My problem**: I am trying to get GCC to vectorize a nested loop.

Compiler flags I added to the basic flags:

```
-fopenmp
-march=native
-msse2 -mfpmath=sse
-ffast-math
-funsafe-math-optimizations
-ftree-vectorize
-fopt-info-vec-missed
```

Variables:

```
  // local variables
  float RTP, RPE, RR=0;
  int SampleLoc, EN;
  float THr;
  long TN;

  // global variables
  extern float PR[MaxX - MinX][MaxY - MinY][MaxZ - MinZ];
  extern float SampleOffset;
  extern float SampleInt; 

  // global defines
  Speed
```

Loops start at line 500. The code is parallelized but not vectorized. Here is the code:

```
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (TN = 0; TN < NumXmtrFoci; TN++) {
    for (XR = XlBound; XR <= XuBound; XR++) {
      for (YR = YlBound; YR <= YuBound; YR++) { 
        for (ZR = ZlBound; ZR <= ZuBound; ZR++) { 
          for (EN = 0; EN < NUM_RCVR_ELE; EN++)  {
           RPE = REP[XR - MinX][YR - MinY][ZR - MinZ][EN]; 
           RTP = RPT[XR - MinX][YR - MinY][ZR - MinZ][TN];
           RR = RPE + RTP + ZT[TN]; 
           SampleLoc = (int)(floor(RR/(SampleInt*Speed) + SampleOffset));
           THr = TimeHistory[SampleLoc][EN];
           PR[XR-MinX][YR-MinY][ZR-MinZ] += THr;
          }  /*for EN*/
        }  /*for ZR*/
      }  /*for YR*/
    }  /*for XR*/ /
  } /*for TN*/
```

The loop bounds are all #define and range from -64 to 128. Loop iterator variables are of type `int`. Inner loop variables are of type float.

A sampling of GCC compiler 'NOT VECTORIZED' message relevant to this loop;
some repeated many times at many places in the code.

```
502|note: not vectorized: multiple nested loops.|
505|note: not vectorized: not suitable for gather load _61 = TimeHistory[_59][_85];|
500|note: not vectorized: no grouped stores in basic block.|
500|note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.|
```

**MY QUESTION IS:** *What do the GCC compiler messages tell me to focus on to get the loop to vectorize?*

I do not understand the messages adequately.  So far online has not provided the answers.  I thought multiple nested loops were not a problem and what are: gather load; grouped stores; data-refs.

Comment: -msse2: useless with -march=native. -mfpmath=sse: useless on x86_64. -funsafe-math-optimizations: useless with -ffast-math. -ftree-vectorize: useless with -O3 (you do have -O3 right?).

Comment: Yes I do.  So i can delete those flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point of the GCC report is that the expression `TimeHistory[SampleLoc][EN]` cannot be easily vectorized unless gather instructions are used. Indeed, `SampleLoc` is a variable that can contains non linear values. Gather instruction are only available in the AVX2/AVX-512 instruction set. You compilation flags indicate you use SSE2 and possible a more advanced instruction set available on the target platform (but this one is not provided). Without AVX2/AVX-512, GCC cannot vectorize the loops because of such non contiguous access pattern. In fact, AVX-2 gather instructions are a bit limited compared to general reads so the compiler may not be able to use them because of that. You can see the list of intrinsics/instructions [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=gather&techs=AVX2). Additionally, the compiler needs to be sure `TimeHistory` is not modified in the loop. THis seems trivial here but in practice arrays can theoretically alias so the compiler can be afraid of a possible aliasing and not vectorise the gather loads because of a possible dependence between each read and next writes. Replicating the last loop may help. Using the `restrict` keyword and `const` can also help.

Comment: Thanks-- but what does ' Replicating the last loop' mean?

Comment: The idea is transform variables like `RPE`, `RR`, etc. to static arrays and fill them like variable are currently filled using the `EM`-based loop. This means having several times an `EM`-based loop. This solution is good to better locate parts that are not vectorized and vectorize parts of the code when others cannot be vectorized (eg. gather issue).

Comment: I appreciate your edits to my question.  Still working with your suggestion of 'several times an EM-based loop' and making a little progress--Thanks